# Publishing a storybook as an npm package

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I have a component library which publishes via `npm publish` to a private registry, so consuming applications can install it via `npm install mypackage@1.0.0` etc.

I have set up a [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) and would like to make the storybook static web app available on this private registry, without bloating the main package. I'd like users to be able to install *either* the main library itself *or* the storybook (not both). I'd also like each published version of the library to have a corresponding storybook i.e. `npm install mypackage@1.0.0` gets you the main library and `npm install mypackage-storybook@1.0.0` (or similar naming convention) gets you the corresponding storybook

How can I achieve this with npm publish?

PS I'm aware of hosted alternatives like https://www.chromatic.com/ but unable to use due to corporate constraints